# Twitter-style time-ago formatting ("2h") with Javascript

Tags: javascript, time, timeago

[Timeago.js](http://timeago.org/) does a great job of formatting time stamps relative to the current time ("about 2 hours ago").

Are there any solutions that accomplish the same thing, but abbreviated? IE "2h", like Twitter uses.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: You could simply use Timeago's language-register function and add this as a new language...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Timeago.js and overwrite the local time formatting with the abbreviated version, e.g.

```
var locale = function(number, index, total_sec) {
  return [
    ['just now', 'right now'],
    ['%s s ago', 'in %s s'],
    ['1 m ago', 'in 1 m'],
    ['%s m ago', 'in %s m'],
    ['1 h ago', 'in 1 h'],
    ['%s h ago', 'in %s h'],
    ....
  ][index];
};

timeago.register('pt_ABBR', locale);
var timeagoInstance = timeago();

// then you can use it
timeagoInstance.format(1473245023718, 'pt_ABBR');
```

Answer (score -1):

In timeago.js, you can simply replace the "strings" hash with the "strings" hash here: https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/blob/master/locales/jquery.timeago.en-short.js

```
  jQuery.timeago.settings.strings = {
    prefixAgo: null,
    prefixFromNow: null,
    suffixAgo: "",
    suffixFromNow: "",
    seconds: "1m",
    minute: "1m",
    minutes: "%dm",
    hour: "1h",
    hours: "%dh",
    day: "1d",
    days: "%dd",
    month: "1mo",
    months: "%dmo",
    year: "1yr",
    years: "%dyr",
    wordSeparator: " ",
    numbers: []
  };
```